# How could I create a static array or list in a class that holds that class' objects c#

Tags: c#, list, class, object, static

I couldn't find anything online so I'm sorry if this question is too basic.

I want to create a class that has a static list which contains all the objects of that class.

Something along these lines:

```
public class PlanetSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<PlanetSpawner> planetList = new List<PlanetSpawner>();

    public PlanetSpawner(Vector3 aStartingCoord, GameObject planet)
    {
        GameObject.Instantiate(planet,aStartingCoord,new Quaternion(0,0,0,0));
        planet.transform.position = aStartingCoord;

        planetList.Add(object that called the constructor);
    }
 
}
```

This code is for a unity script and the object is created in another method (and class):

```
public GameObject planetPrefab;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    PlanetSpawner testPlanet = new PlanetSpawner(new Vector3(1, 1, 1), planetPrefab);
}
```

I know I could do this instead:

```
public GameObject planet;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    PlanetSpawner testPlanet = new PlanetSpawner(new Vector3(1, 1, 1), planet);
    PlanetSpawner.planetList.Add(testPlanet);
}
```

and modify the constructor:

```
public class PlanetSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<PlanetSpawner> planetList = new List<PlanetSpawner>();

    public PlanetSpawner(Vector3 aStartingCoord, GameObject planet)
    {
        GameObject.Instantiate(planet,aStartingCoord,new Quaternion(0,0,0,0));
        planet.transform.position = aStartingCoord;
    }

 
}
```

But I believe the way I want to do it is cleaner and a little bit easier to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `this` to refer to the current object:

```
public class PlanetSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<PlanetSpawner> planetList = new List<PlanetSpawner>();

    public PlanetSpawner(Vector3 aStartingCoord, GameObject planet)
    {
        GameObject.Instantiate(planet,aStartingCoord,new Quaternion(0,0,0,0));
        planet.transform.position = aStartingCoord;

        planetList.Add(this);
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community!

I see this is Unity3D related question, consider joining [game dev exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) for more game development related questions and answers.

## Problems

Firstly, [don't use constructors with MonoBehaviours](https://answers.unity.com/questions/862032/c-constructor-in-monobehaviour.html).

Secondly, class itself should not track its instances count. Make a second class, e.g. *PlanetsContainer*, which would track all those instances.

Thirdly, to separate logic, have planet data, creation and instances tracking on seperate classes, e.g. *PlanetInstance*, *PlanetsSpawner*, *PlanetsContainer*. *PlanetsSpawner* should be responsible only for instantiating planets (and maybe adding spawned planets to *PlanetsContainer*).

## Solution

I'm providing complete source just to clarify the idea.

#### PlanetInstance.cs

```
public class PlanetInstance : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Your planet data here
}
```

#### PlanetsContainer.cs

```
public class PlanetsContainer
{
    public readonly List<PlanetInstance> planets;


    public PlanetsContainer() : this(0)
    { }

    public PlanetsContainer(int initialSize)
    {
        planets = new List<PlanetInstance>(initialSize);
    }
}
```

#### PlanetsSpawner.cs

```
public class PlanetsSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PlanetInstance _defaultPlanetPrefab;

    private PlanetsContainer _planetsContainer;
    

    private void Awake()
    {
        _planetsContainer = new PlanetsContainer();
    }


    public void SpawnPlanet(Vector3 startingCoord, PlanetInstance prefab = null)
    {
        var prefabToSpawn = prefab ?? _defaultPlanetPrefab;

        var spawnedPlanet = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn, startingCoord, Quaternion.identity);
        _planetsContainer.planets.Add(spawnedPlanet);
    }

}
```